# "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error for best SQA Week link from Leagues page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

Perhaps this is limited to the specific case, but anyway: for the [Leagues - Top Stack Exchange users per week, month, quarter, and year](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) page clicking on best this week userpic for [SQA](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/) resulted in that lovely panda:

[image: OOPS!!!]

The only special thing about the user - it's SQA [user:1
**Nick Craver**](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/1/nick-craver), and his last and only rep change is +100 (must be association bonus) on May 3, 2011.

Random checks of about 20 similar links did not reveal any issues.

Testing environment (for the record): `Win7 Ultimate SP1 x64 / FF 18.0.2`

QA at your service.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-reproduced]. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a load error the previous night of the reputation history from the SQA site - a casualty of a bad query plan elsewhere.  The job last night ran fine, so this is now behaving correctly.

Comment: passed QA, confirmed as fixed) thanks Nick!